# selected option by default in symfony forms entity type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

hi everybody can anyone please help me in this i want to know how can i make an specific item selected by default with entity type in form in symfony2 i try preferred_choice & data but i doesn't work can anybody please help & thank you a lot thank's

```
->add('idpays','entity', 
 array('class'=>'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Pays','property'=>'namePaysUppercase',
 'multiple' => false,
 'data' => ('TUNISIA'),
 'label' => 'Pays','read_only'=>'true')
 );
```

Comment: Just a side note: use nameCountryUppercase instead of namePaysUppercase. Combining two languages like this makes things very confusing. First, another developer would need to know specifically these 2 languages. Then, you get unfortunate translations such as getAction. If you're writing an application dealing with stock prices, that would be extremely confusing which "action" you mean. I have seen many such occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Your data should be an entity form `Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Pays` for working !

The best is to set it in your controller.

```
...
$pays = new Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Pays();
$pays->setName('MyPays');

$formItem->setPays($pays);
$form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), $formItem);
...
```